# Estandarizar variables para cumplir una fórmula

Tags: python

¿Cómo puedo crear una funcion para estandarizar variables en python cumpliendo la siguiente fórmula?

```
z = (x - u) / s
```

Es un caso académico, no logro crear uno al parecer que cumpla con lo requerido.

Comment: Hola Paola, te damos la bienvenida a la comunidad. Por favor, edita la pregunta para añadir más detalles y aclarar el problema, ¿a qué te refieres con estandarizar variables cumpliendo una fórmula? ¿Qué es la fórmula que compartes? Y también muy importante: ¿qué has intentado y con qué errores te estás encontrando? Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla).

Comment: Supongo que es la formula para el calculo del z-score... Como comenta Álvaro falta mucha información ¿Cuál es el problema exactamente? ¿Tienes que implementarlo todo desde cero o puedes usar la biblioteca estándar o de terceros? ¿Cuál es la entrada para la función y la salida esperada? ¿Te dan la media (u) y la desviación estándar (s)? ¿una muestra de los datos?...